# Crontab doesn't run my schedule backup on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, backup, crontab

I created a backupfolder in my root directory. Following is my command to run a backup task in crontab -e:

```
* * * * * sudo tar -cvpzf /backupfolder/user1_backup-$(date +%Y--%m-%d).tar.gz /home/students/user1
```

I tried to backup user1 account to the backupfolder in anytime, but somehow, I couldn't locate any backup file in the backupfolder....

Is there any mistakes with my command above?

I tried this command:

```
sudo tar -cvpzf user1_backup-$(date +%Y--%m-%d).tar.gz /home/students/user1
```

no issues was found and it managed to backup well. Can someone guides me with this? Thank you!

EDIT:
FOllowing is my output for grep CRON /var/log/syslog:
[cron syslog](http://codepad.org/Dqy2KiBm)

Comment: The command you are executing is `tar sudo tar -cvpzf ...`. Is that really what you intended? (Check `man 5 crontab`, particularly for the set of fields.)

Comment: Also, consider not running this through `sudo`. Rather, just give yourself write permission into /backupfolder.

Comment: Here's my modification but seems it still don't work : `* * * * * tar -cvpzf /backupfolder/user1_backup-$(date +\%Y--\%m-\%d).tar.gz /home/students/user1`
 but it still doesn't work... @MichaelKjörling

Comment: Try running the modified crontab entry through `sudo`. If that works, you most likely need write permission into /backupfolder, as Michael Kjörling suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page for crontab](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/crontab/):

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

You must escape your % characters in your crontab entry, as follows:

```
* * * * * sudo tar -cvpzf /backupfolder/user1_backup-$(date +\%Y--\%m-\%d).tar.gz /home/students/user1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, however, I have modified the command based on your suggestion: `* * * * * tar -cvpzf /backupfolder/user1_backup-$(date +\%Y--\%m-\%d).tar.gz /home/students/user1`
 but it still doesn't work...

Comment: You can check the logfile to see if it tells you anything by running `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` - please edit your original post to include any relevant findings.

Comment: Hi, I have shown the output file in my edited post. Thank you.

Comment: Problem solved, I should execute `sudo crontab -e` instead of `crontab -e` when editing my crontab. Thank you very much for reminding me about the \%date format.

Comment: That most likely means you didn't have the necessary write permissions to write to the folder you were trying to write to. Running `sudo crontab -e` will edit the crontab entries for the root user (i.e. they will run as root).